# Text boxes in LibreOffice Writer unreadable

Tags: libreoffice, ubuntu-20.04, libreoffice-writer

The text boxes are not rendering correctly and seems to be superimposing the new font size and style every time I change style by shortcut (`Ctrl + 1` to use `Heading 1`, for example).

Are there any fixes for this?

(I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, LibreOffice Writer 6.4.7.2)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem simply by installing the latest version of LibreOffice (7.1.5.2) from their official website. It was probably just a bug in my specific version of LibreOffice.